# Ms acess 2 querys para as mesmas comboboxes

Tags: sql, query, microsoft-access, combobox

Boas a todos estou a programar uma base de dados e gostaria de ter uma espécie de 3 querys.
Vou tentar ser o mais preciso possível.
Tenho 2 caixas de combinação que estão interligadas, neste caso especifico Marca e Modelo, sendo que quando escolho a marca so me mostra o modelo tal como eu queria, mas num outro formulário tenho uma situação que me tem dado bastantes dores de cabeça pois não há maneira de descobrir como o fazer.

formulario inserir carro
Neste formulario insiro o numero interno do veiculo e uso a query que falei acima.

formulario inserir peça
Neste eu gostaria de fazer algo diferente.
Ter uma caixa de texto em que insiro o numero interno do carro e o access vai automaticamente buscar os dados que inseri na tabela no formulário anterior mas caso não esteja presente esse numero eu queria que fizesse o que faz no formulário inserir carro.
Caso queira deixar livre o mesmo funciona mas se quiser fazer uma pesquisa dos dados dos carros inseridos perco a query que me faz a marca e o modelo estarem interligados..... posso fornecer o projecto se ajudar a alguém.

Comment: Beleza, @FredericoOliveira, sugiro que você leia o [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour](tour), Edite sua pergunta com o seu progresso, sem isso é dificil ajudar

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO
Descobri posso fazer a query.
O que queria era mesmo isto que tá em codigo.

```
'UPDATE DE MARCA, MODELO, MOTORIZAÇÃO, ANO INICIO, ANO FIM, DATA MATRICULA, NUMERO DE PORTAS E COMBUSTIVEL QUANDO VFV EXISTIR
Private Sub Comando713_Click()
If Not IsNull(Me!Texto689.Value) Then
    Me!Combinação65.Value = DLookup("[MARCA]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Combinação69.Value = DLookup("[MODELO]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Texto73.Value = DLookup("[ANO INICIAL]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Texto75.Value = DLookup("[ANO FINAL]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Texto137.Value = DLookup("[MOTORIZAÇÃO]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Combinação611.Value = DLookup("[NUMERO DE PORTAS]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Texto137.Value = DLookup("[MOTORIZAÇÃO]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Texto445.Value = DLookup("[CODIGO MOTOR]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Combinação435.Value = DLookup("[COMBUSTIVEL]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me.Texto696.SetFocus
    Me.Combinação65.AllowValueListEdits = False
End If
End Sub
```

Agora precisava que quando faço o DLookup os varios campos mudem para não editaveis.
Tentei este codigo sem sucesso:

```
Me.Combinação65.AllowValueListEdits = False
```